# Is it possible to use LoadLibrary from a dll in Borland C++ from a given path?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, loadlibrary, borland-c++

I have a C++ dll which loads a C++ CLI library using LoadLibrary function as follows:

```
HMODULE myDLL = LoadLibrary("DLLtoBeLoaded.dll");
```

and this works.
But I want my "DLLtoBeLoaded.dll" in a different directory(Different from the executable directory). So I tried:

```
HMODULE myDLL = LoadLibrary("C:\\DLLtoBeLoaded.dll");
```

This does not work. Although myDLL is not null after this but DLLtoBeLoaded.dll's constructor is not called.

**EDIT**

MyDLL is not null because LoadLibrary is actually successful. But the reason why it did not seem to work was that the DLLtoBeLoaded.dll references some dlls which are also not in executable directory(The program works if I just copy referenced dlls in executable folder). Is it possible to keep the referenced dlls in different folder from executable?

Comment: Can it be that your App has not the right to access that path. Got a similar problem with VS. Especially in debug.

Comment: No, the executable has appropriate rights. Here is what I am trying to do:
Executable loads a dll(Dll_1) which is in a different folder from the executable -> The loaded dll(Dll_1) loads another dll(Dll_2) which is in the same folder as Dll_1 but both the dlls are not in executable folder.
But I think as the executable is loading first dll, it's working however the second dll is loaded by another dll. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Are the 2 sets of _.dlls_ (from the exe and the other folder) incompatible? Could it be that your loading _other dll1_ and that one is trying to load _exe dll2_? Could you give it a shot with the same 2 dlls in both folders? You'll have to go deeper (in dll1) to see exactly where it fails.

Comment: @CristiFati The dlls are compatible, I am sure about it because when I keep the second dll in executable folder, it works as expected, I can call it's functions without any errors.

Comment: If copying the _exe dll1_ over _other dll1_, does it still fail?

Comment: @ CristiFati.. I could not understand what you said. dll1 and dll2 are two different dlls, I can't copy one over the other. I tried calling 'GetLastError ()' after LoadLibrary and I am getting 203 error code.

Comment: 1. try to change actual directory before loading dll.  2. have you tried also `//` or `/` or `\ ` I am not using **C#** but have seen a lot of variations of the path separator over the years so i always first check all the combinations... 3. if nothing works you should add the path to search paths of the OS

Comment: @Spektre.. I did try both the things you have suggested. Still no luck!

Comment: It's working now. The problem was that the DLLToBeLoaded.dll references some other dlls and the runtime is trying to find those dlls in the executable directory. So I tried putting the referenced dlls in the executable directory and dll to be loaded in 'C:\\DLLtoBeLoaded.dll' and it works. But I want even the referenced dlls in same folder as DLLtoBeLoaded.dll. Anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to reference dlls from a different folder than the executable.
Whenever the runtime fails to load the referenced assemblies, it fires Assembly Resolver event. 
I got the basic idea from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) link.
There are other methods too (probing and code base). But I liked this one the most.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SetDllDirectory` or simply `SetCurrentDirectory` before first `LoadLibrary` to set DLL directory (to `C:\` in your example).